# Core Java and Advance Java (what's the difference?)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I was googling Java tutorials and related news to Java, until I saw this "Core Java" now I am wondering what really is core Java?  And what's the difference with Advanced Java?  Is that another Java programming language?  What are the topics under Core Java? And Advanced Java?

BTW can you suggest a good book for learning Advanced Java and Core Java? My first book was Java how to program 8th edition, and basically I know the fundamentals already.  So all I need is another book to learn Core Java and Advanced Java.  And is core Java the same as Java EE?  What is a good book to learn Java EE?

Comment: How about... [Core Java](http://www.amazon.com/Core-Java-I--Fundamentals-8th-Horstmann/dp/0132354764/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1316833029&sr=8-1) and [Core Java, Advanced Features](http://www.amazon.com/Core-Java-Vol-Advanced-Features/dp/0132354799/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1316833029&sr=8-2)?

Comment: Updated my question, can you also suggest a book for Java EE?

Comment: BTW - now you know core Java, please try and consistently spell it correctly, it is Java (not java or JAVA).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Core / Advanced distinction in the tutorials *should be viewed* as being purely about learning about Java, and what order it is advisable to learn things.

> I am wondering what really is Core Java?

It is the basic stuff you should learn first.

> and what's the difference with Advanced Java?

Advanced Java is the stuff that you shouldn't try to understand until you are comfortable with the basics.

> is that another Java programming language?

No.  And it is not a different library.  In fact, you won't see the core/advanced distinction in the documentation or packaging of the language or libraries.  (According to one interpretation, "Core Java" is everything in Java SE ... but frankly, that is not a useful classification; see below.)

> what are the topics under Core Java? and Advanced Java?

There is no absolute answer to this.  It depends on who has made the classification.  The best thing is to look at the table of contents for the book, tutorial, course syllabus, whatever.

---

Independently of the above, Oracle also uses the phrase "Core Java technologies" in marketing / PR documents to refer to the stuff in Java SE.  Here is an example:

- [Java SE Core Technologies](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/index-jsp-137187.html)

This says:

> *The Core Java technologies and application programming interfaces (APIs) are the foundation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE).*

... without saying clearly what they are referring to.  The take-away (for me is that "Java Core" versus other things is an *imprecise* classification.

Some of the stuff that is included in the "core" technologies (see above link) are either specialized or (more or less) legacy technology.  With Java 8 they have started to modularizing the Java APIs (c.f. the "compact profiles") and this is moving forward with Java 9 modules, and the deprecation of parts of CORBA support.

Then if you look in the various official Oracle Java Glossaries; e.g.

- [Oracle Technology Network > Java > Glossary](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/glossary-135216.html)
- [J2EE 1.4 Glossary](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/index-jsp-137187.html)

you probably won't find a definition for "Core Java".  (I couldn't!)

All of this means that *in reality* when you see a Job or Position Description that calls for "Core Java", it probably means that person who wrote it probably does not mean "Core Java" in the sense of the [Java SE Core Technologies](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/index-jsp-137187.html) page.  (Or if they do mean that, then they are unrealistic about the actual job requirements!)

Comment: +1 - Your answer on the difference between core and advanced Java is simple, but complete.

Comment: Thank so much for the kind answer :) Appreciate it Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that `core!=basic`.

1. Core Java - **J2SE**
2. Non-core Java - everything else that is *not* J2SE (J2EE, JAI, JOGL, JMF, ..)
3. Advanced Java - made up term with a different meaning for everyone that is asked.

Answer (score 1):

For Java EE I would start with an online tutorial, just so you can get familiar with parts, and decide if you need a book, and what parts of Java EE you want to get more information on.

http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/

For Core java I think this is nice:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

As to which books to get, once you have gone through these you will get an idea where you want to focus more.  For example, do you want to get better at graphics or concurrency?  There are books more geared toward these.  Perhaps you want to understand JavaServer Faces, then you can  get a book on that.

You stated you know the fundamentals, but that is a pretty broad area, so you may want to first go through and not only have read about these topics, but experiment with them, so you can know what you do and don't know.